# Find $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})-1}{x} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to find that limit
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})-1}{x} $$

I can use there L'Hospital's rule, so let's calculate 
$$ (\cos(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})-1)' = (\cos(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})' = \\
(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})'\cdot \sin(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)}) = \\
\sin(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)} \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)}} $$
So
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})-1}{x} = \\ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\sin(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)} \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)}} = \sin(\sqrt{\pi / 2}) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi / 2}}  $$

but wolfram tells that it is $-\infty$

Comment: Does $\cot^{-1}$ denote $\text{arccot}$?

Comment: You cannot use de l’Hopital rules since the limit is not of the form $\frac00$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: Are you sure it is $\cot^{-1}$ and not $\tan^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $\cot^{-1}$ is the inverse of the $\cot$ function.

Depending on what your definition is (more specifically the range of $\cot^{-1}$), it can be that $\cot^{-1}(x) \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ when $x \to 0$ or  $\cot^{-1}(x) \to \pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ when $x\to 0$, depending on the sign of $x$. In each case, the numerator does not tend to $0$ and you cannot use L'Hôpital's rule.

Now, if you are using the first definition, since the numerator is negative when $x \to 0$, and the denominator can be either positive or negative when $x \to 0$, the left limit and the right limit are not equal and hence the limit does not exist.

If you are using the other definition, then the under-limit function isn't defined for $x<0$ and we define the "total" limit to be the right limit, which is equal to $-\infty$.

Comment: With the usual branches, $\cot^{-1}(x) \approx \frac{\pi}{2}$ for small positive $x$, and $\approx -\frac{\pi}{2}$ for small negative $x$.  Now for $x < 0$, if you then take the principal branch of the square root, you have the cosine of an imaginary number, which is greater than 1, and so the denominator is positive.  I guess this accounts for Wolfram's statement that the limit is simply $-\infty$.

Comment: @NateEldredge It depends on how you define it, I usually define it the other way. But, I will update my answer to address this.

Comment: In use of Taylor I get $ +/- \infty$ so limit doesn't exists...

Comment: @trolley It is $\pm \infty$ (i.e. doesn't exist) if you define $\cot^{-1} : \mathbb R \to (0, \pi)$, but it is $-\infty$ if you define $\cot^{-1} : \mathbb R \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \backslash \{0\}$. Which definition are you using?

Comment: the second one, but look. I will show you my steps. As I calculated a derivative of top (let name it $f'(x)$ ) in $0$ is equal to $f'(0) = \sin(\sqrt{\pi / 2}) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi / 2}} $ so $\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(x)})-1}{x}  = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\pi / 2}) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi / 2}} + o(x)}{x} $ and $o(x)/x \rightarrow 0$ so $\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\pi / 2}) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi / 2}}}{x} \rightarrow (+/-) \infty$

Comment: @trolley I will not get into whether you calculated $f'(0)$ correctly. But, first, by Taylor we have $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+o(x)$.

Comment: chmm, ok but I didn't assume in my calculations the first (or second) definition of arccot so why get $\pm \infty$?

Comment: @trolley I meant that you get $\pm \infty$ according to your steps, which are incorrect. Sorry, I should have made it clear

Comment: why incorrect? I know that I miss $f(0)$ but with that I get $ \pm \infty$ too

Comment: @trolley The thing is that the function that you are taking the limit of is not defined for $x < 0$, so $x$ is positive. Strictly speaking the limit doesn't exist. But, if a function is only defined on the right side of a point, we define the "total" limit to be equal to the right limit. This is because it makes no sense to talk about a limit where a function is not defined.

Comment: Ahh, currently I understand! Thanks a lot for great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an indetermined form because $\sqrt{\cot^{-1}(0)}$ isn't an angle which gives the value 1 to the cosine. So we have a finite value divided to a variable wich goes to zero, follows that the limit diverges.